# calling another template in Regex

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I have the below piece of XML

```
<title>Conduct of external affairs <content-style font-style="italic">via</content-style> NGOs</title>
```

here when i'm trying to match with REGEX it is throwing me an error

The template i'm using is

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xslt:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="Conjunction">(of)|(to)|(and)|(the)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:call-template name="changeUpperCase">
      <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="changeUpperCase">
    <xsl:param name="Text"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $EachToken in tokenize(lower-case($Text), ' ')
                          return
                          if(matches($EachToken, $Conjunction))
                           then
                             $EachToken
                           else
                           concat(upper-case(substring($EachToken, 1, 1)), substring($EachToken, 2))"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xslt:stylesheet>
```

the error i'm getting is

```
 XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/The%20Law%20of%20the%20Hong%20Kong%20Constitution/The%20Law%20of%20the%20Hong%20Kong%20Constitution/XSLT/Chapters.xsl:39: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

i also declared a template for content-style, but i'm unable to know how to link it.

```
<xsl:template match="content-style">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@format">
        <span class="{concat('format-',@format)}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:template>
```

but the above template is working if i use the below XML piece of code

```
<title>IS HONG KONG AN INTERNATIONAL PERSON?</title>
```

Case 2:

```
 <title>PREPARATION FOR TRANSFER OF SOVEREIGNTY</title>
```

this should be converted to

```
Preperation for Transfer of Sovereignty
```

please let me know how i can solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a consistent style of code with matching templates instead of called templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="Conjunction">(of)|(to)|(and)|(the)|(for)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="for $EachToken in tokenize(lower-case(.), ' ')
                          return
                          if(matches($EachToken, $Conjunction))
                           then
                             $EachToken
                           else
                           concat(upper-case(substring($EachToken, 1, 1)), substring($EachToken, 2))"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style">
     <xsl:variable name="fontStyle" select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style[@format]">
        <span class="{concat('format-',@format)}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the error simply vanishes as now there is a template for the `text` child nodes of your `title` elements processed by the `apply-templates`.

In your current code `with-param name="Text" select="text()"` you are passing a sequence of `text` child nodes to the template if the element has mixed content and that way the `lower-case` call has the wrong type of arguments.

The templates for `content-style` elements should now be applied as well but I am not sure they will do exactly what you want as you have not specified that in detail. Post a new question if there are still problems with that second part of your question.

Based on your comments I have revised the stylesheet to use `analyze-string`:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="Conjunction">^(of|to|and|the|for)$</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w)(\w*)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="if (matches(., $Conjunction, 'i'))
                  then lower-case(.)
                  else concat(upper-case(regex-group(1)), lower-case(regex-group(2)))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style">
     <xsl:variable name="fontStyle" select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style[@format]">
        <span class="{concat('format-',@format)}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now Saxon 9.5 transforms

```
<root>
  <title>HOW HIGH IS THE &#x201C;HIGH DEGREE OF AUTONOMY&#x2019; OF HONG KONG?</title>
  <title>PREPARATION FOR TRANSFER OF SOVEREIGNTY</title>
  <title>Conduct of external affairs <content-style font-style="italic">via</content-style> NGOs</title>
</root>
```

into

```
  <title>How High Is the “High Degree of Autonomy’ of Hong Kong?</title>
  <title>Preparation for Transfer of Sovereignty</title>
  <title>Conduct of External Affairs <span class="font-style-italic">via</span> Ngos</title>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin this worked like charm. Thank you verymuch. But i need a small tweek in the template you gave above, i need to see of the first letter is caps if it is not it should be me capitalized. Thanks again please see my question case 2.

Comment: I think the code we have currently would transform `Preparation For transfer of sovereignty` to `Preparation For Transfer of Sovereignty` so the `t` of `transfer` is transformed to `T`. What else is missing?

Comment: I'm sorry for wrong input, i've updated it now, actually i need to convert `PREPARATION FOR TRANSFER OF SOVEREIGNTY` to `Preperation for Transfer of Sovereignty` but now it is converted as `Preparation For transfer of sovereignty` and also `HOW HIGH IS THE &#x201C;HIGH DEGREE OF AUTONOMY&#x2019; OF HONG KONG?` is not getting converted correctly.

Comment: @user2423959, I have edited the stylesheet to change the `param` to `<xsl:param name="Conjunction">(of)|(to)|(and)|(the)|(for)</xsl:param>`. Now when I transform `<title>PREPARATION FOR TRANSFER OF SOVEREIGNTY</title>` with Saxon 9.5 I get `Preparation for Transfer of Sovereignty`. For `HOW HIGH IS THE &#x201C;HIGH DEGREE OF AUTONOMY&#x2019; OF HONG KONG?` you would first need to tell us which result you want and which one you currently get.

Comment: Hi @Martin. sorry for the delay in reply. I want the output to be `How High is the “High Degree of Autonomy’ of Hong Kong?`

Comment: @user2423959, I have added a second stylesheet with a different approach to find words and manipulate the case of letters. I hope that solves your problem.